# PHP disable remote sites fetching my content

Tags: php, mysql, search

How can I disable remote sites from fetching content from my site or flooding it alltogether? There's bunch of meta-search websites which grab content from my site by sending tons of search queries and killing my mysql server. How can I prevent this in PHP? I want to be able for only real visitors to use the search.

would something like this work?

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']!="myserver") header("Location: http://www.myhomepage.com");
```

Comment: Use `robots.txt` file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948267/result-from-serverhttp-referer-when-referer-header-is-not-sent-to-server

Comment: http referer is not set by many browsers :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No single measure will do, but a combination can help:

1. You could check the referrer, but many browsers ommit it, so I advise against it.
2. If searches are the problem, you should use a random **challenge token** in the search form.
3. Cache your stuff.
4. Use **robots.txt**. The big players will obey.
5. Block bad user agents that contain "crawler" or alike. Be carefull not to block google :)