# How do I detect the site a user has navigated from?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm developing a simple website using `PHP`, `HTML` and `JS`, and I'd like to have the page footer change based on what site the user came from. For example:

```
if user is from google.com
  use footer-1.php
if user is from qwerty.com
  use footer-2.php
```

Is there a way to detect the site a user has navigated from?

## **Update (here is the solution I use, pasting JS into footer.php):**

```
sessionStorage.setItem("referent", document.referrer);
          
if (sessionStorage.referent.search('google') >= 0) {
    console.log("Your message");
    //Your code

}
```

Comment: You want to read about the "REFERRER" http header. But also note that this is _not_ reliable and can be easily faked.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948283/529024

Comment: note, the header is referer - yes, it's misspelled and is part of the spec now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result from $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_REFERER'\], when referer header is not sent to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948267/result-from-serverhttp-referer-when-referer-header-is-not-sent-to-server)

Comment: Can someone explain ELI5 how to use refferer via PHP?

Answer (score 1):

See `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

```
$previous_page = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to check if the user is coming from google.com or anyotherdomain.com unless there is additional information in the query string.

Like

```
https://www.anydomain.com?source=google
```

Now, Search Engine like Google.com doesn't really add Query string like this.
So it's not possible to find out the source of the request.

I hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Check the comments above, Sourabh. It _is_ possible.